# How to remove aldryn-newsblog articles from django CMS menu

Tags: django-cms

I use "aldryn-newsblog" addon on my django CMS project and my menu items come from CMS Pages automatically. When I add "Blog page" into menu it comes with blog articles as submenu items (it can be seen below). Submenu can be cancelled on menu but in a same time I need to use submenu feature.

How I can solve this, can anyone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjucT.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to hide articles from the menu on an individual basis?

Comment: Individually hiding is would better but it is enough for me that all articles can be hidden. I only want to see "Blog" on the menu without any articles as sub.